# Scroll not working for multiple RecyclerView in BottomSheet

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I implemented `BottomSheet` using the `DialogFragment` approach. I have a `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` in the `BottomSheet`. The `ViewPager` is hosting 2 pages, each inflates a `RecyclerView`. The first(Coffee tab) `RecyclerView` scrolls fine. The problem I'm having now is that for the 2nd(Milk tab) the scroll is not working. Any idea how can I fix this? Thanks!

You can test out with the demo project I created here: https://github.com/choongyouqi/bottomsheet`

[image]

Comment: Im betting its not inflating correctly. Do you have it set for vertical?

Comment: Check my answer below no any extra library used not any bugs is their as stated in other answers just check my `Static Fragment` code and apply that to yours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ViewPager with RecyclerView works incorrectly inside BottomSheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715822/android-viewpager-with-recyclerview-works-incorrectly-inside-bottomsheet)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned by R. Zagórski, I described the reason for this scrolling behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38281457/6507689), i.e., `BottomSheetBehavior` only supports one scrolling child. However this answer wasn't focusing on Bottom Sheet Dialogs.

Therefore – just like R. Zagórski – I extended my own [library](https://github.com/laenger/ViewPagerBottomSheet) that overcomes this limitation.
Starting with **0.0.3** there is support for Bottom Sheet Dialogs! You can find the library and the example app here:
https://github.com/laenger/ViewPagerBottomSheet

To use in your project, simply add the maven repo url to your build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://raw.github.com/laenger/maven-releases/master/releases" }
}
```

Add the library to the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile "biz.laenger.android:vpbs:0.0.3"
}
```

Use `ViewPagerBottomSheetDialogFragment` as super class for Dialog Fragments. Then setup any ViewPager inside the content view:

```
public class DialogFragment extends ViewPagerBottomSheetDialogFragment {
    @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        final View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dialog_bottom_sheet, null);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) contentView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        // ...
        BottomSheetUtils.setupViewPager(viewPager);

        dialog.setContentView(contentView);
    }
}
```

[image: sample implementation]

Comment: Can you help me to implement this in persistent bottom sheet rather than modal bottom sheet, i tried using the vbps library but it got some issues in it for which i have already raised a issue on the git repo.

Comment: answered in the mentioned [issue](https://github.com/laenger/ViewPagerBottomSheet/issues/22)

Comment: If you're working with AndroidX you can check https://github.com/svrlopatrik/ViewPagerBottomSheet

Comment: 5 years later, this is still not fixed.

Answer (score 17):

use this view as root view:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class DisallowInterceptView extends LinearLayout {
    public DisallowInterceptView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }

    public DisallowInterceptView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }

    public DisallowInterceptView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }


    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

then in your layout that used for bottmSheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.your.package.DisallowInterceptView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:maxHeight="400dp"
    android:minHeight="300dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    ...
</LinearLayout>

</com.your.package.DisallowInterceptView>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot

Comment: This code solved my problem after 6 hours of debugging. Thank you so much!

Comment: Working like a charm!. Seems this saved my time.

Answer (score 6):

When trying to look for the problem on StackOverflow I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38281457/6507689). It depicts the bug (at least that is how I look at it), that `BottomSheetBehaviour` works only for the first scrollable child it finds. It also proposes the usage of different `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` proposed and published [here](https://github.com/laenger/ViewPagerBottomSheet/blob/master/vpbs/src/main/java/biz/laenger/android/vpbs/ViewPagerBottomSheetBehavior.java).

However, your case is a bit different. `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is used. And this is where the provided solution does not work. However, I managed to overcome this problem. Published [repository](https://github.com/RobertZagorski/ViewPagerBottomSheet), where your project was modified to be working. It uses the `ViewPagerBottomSheetBehavior` from the library mentioned earlier.

Basically, the following changes were made:

1. `StatisticFragment` extends `ViewPagerBottomSheetDialogFragment` and not `BottomSheetDialogFragment`
2. The onCreateDialog function in `StatisticsFragment` is changed:

   ```
   @NonNull
   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ViewPagerBottomSheetDialog dialog = (ViewPagerBottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
       View rootView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.sheet_main, null);
       viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
       tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
       dialog.setContentView(rootView);
       mBehavior = ViewPagerBottomSheetBehavior.from((View) rootView.getParent());
       mBehavior.setPeekHeight(400);
       if (viewPager != null && tabLayout != null) {
           initViewPager();
       }
       return dialog;
   }
   ```
3. The following function is invoked on the `ViewPager`:

   ```
   BottomSheetUtils.setupViewPager(viewPager);
   ```

And that is all. The project works.

> The following is done behind the scenes:

`BottomSheetDialogFragment` has only one method:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new BottomSheetDialog(getContext(), getTheme());
}
```

There `BottomSheetDialog` is returned. However, it has statically defined behaviour set to `BottomSheetBehavior`. What was needed was to override `ViewPagerBottomSheetDialogFragment` to return `ViewPagerBottomSheetDialog` where it's `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` is set to `ViewPagerBottomSheetBehavior`. Also, the custom `BottomSheet` was needed to be overriden to accustom to `ViewPagerBottomSheetBehavior`.

Comment: it doesnt work for me :(. I only can scroll the items of first viewpager item .Its the same problem with this library too

Comment: Can you help me to implement this in persistent bottom sheet rather than modal bottom sheet, i tried using the vbps library but it got some issues in it for which i have already raised a issue on the git repo.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, to fix this without the need to override BottomSheetBehavior or the need of an additional library you can to the following:
Implement a callback inside your bottom sheet implementation that registers changes of the page.

```
fun onPageChanged(currentPage: Int) {
   recycler1.isNestedScrollingEnabled = currentPage == 0
   recycler2.isNestedScrollingEnabled = currentPage == 1
   dialog?.findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)?.requestLayout()
}
```

In the BottomSheetBehavior implementation in onLayoutChild a lookup for the first child that supports nested scrolling is performed, with this change the lookup is repeated. Not optimal solution but works fine in my case

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2 RecyclerView in CoordinatorLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
         android:id="@+id/mainBottomSheet"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@color/white">

         <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                  android:id="@+id/recyclerViewRight"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent" />

         <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                  android:id="@+id/recyclerViewLeft"
                  android:layout_width="200dp"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

check this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46681326/4797289)

Answer (score 0):

A better solution for this issue is to add the following lines to proguard rules:

```
-keep class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$LayoutParams { int position; }
-keep class com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior { *** findScrollingChild(...); }
```

More details about this can be found on this link: https://github.com/kafumi/android-bottomsheet-viewpager#proguardr8

Answer (score -1):

You not need to  extends `StatisticFragment` as `ViewPagerBottomSheetDialogFragment` or no need to use any Library for that.

It's you code i have just made some changes in your `Static Fragment` related to `View Pager.`

Here is the `Statistic Fragment` in which i have made changes.

**There is not any bugs as stated in all above Answers.**

Replace this code with your old `Static fragment` only not any other changes it will give you the Desired output.

I have just made changes around with your `View Pager` only and made it working as you want.
used `OnPageChangeListener` method just get that view.

**Statistic Fragment.java**

```
    public class StatisticFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

        private BottomSheetBehavior mBehavior;
        private TabLayout tabLayout;
        private ViewPager viewPager;

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
            View rootView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.sheet_main, null);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            if (viewPager != null && tabLayout != null) {
                initViewPager();
            }

            final ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    View view = viewPager.findViewWithTag(arg0);
                    if (view == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getContext());
                    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);
                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            };

            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
            viewPager.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pageChangeListener.onPageSelected(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
                }
            });


            dialog.setContentView(rootView);
            mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) rootView.getParent());
            return dialog;


        }

        private void initViewPager() {
            CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getContext());
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            //mBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            //mBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }

        public class ServiceVideHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            protected ViewGroup mItemView;
            protected TextView mNameView;
            protected TextView mCodeView;

            public ServiceVideHolder(View v) {
                super(v);
                //rootView = v;
                mItemView = (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.item);
                mNameView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.main_text);
                mCodeView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sub_text);
            }
        }

        public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            protected TextView mMainText;
            protected TextView mSubText;

            public ItemViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);
                mMainText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.main_text);
                mSubText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sub_text);
            }
        }

        public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewHolder> {
            private List<Item> items;

            public ItemAdapter(List<Item> items) {
                this.items = items;
            }

            @Override
            public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
                return new ItemViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
                final Item item = items.get(position);
                viewHolder.mMainText.setText(item.name);
                viewHolder.mSubText.setText(item.value);
                viewHolder.mMainText.setTextColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), position % 2 == 0 ? R.color.md_red_500 : R.color.md_blue_500, null));
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return items.size();
            }
        }

        class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
            private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
            private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

            public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
                super(manager);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return mFragmentList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mFragmentList.size();
            }

            public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
                mFragmentList.add(fragment);
                mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
            }
        }

        public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

            private Context mContext;

            public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
                mContext = context;
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
                //CustomPagerEnum customPagerEnum = CustomPagerEnum.values()[position];
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter, collection, false);
                rootView.setTag(position);


                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Inside Instanciate Item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //View rootView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.adapter, null);
                final RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

                if (position == 0) {
                    items.add(new Item("Coffee 1", "1"));
                    items.add(new Item("Coffee 2", "2"));
                    items.add(new Item("Coffee 3", "3"));
                    items.add(new Item("Coffee 4", "4"));
                    items.add(new Item("Coffee 5", "5"));
                    items.add(new Item("Coffee 6", "6"));
                    items.add(new Item("Coffee 7", "7"));
                    items.add(new Item("Coffee 8", "8"));
                    items.add(new Item("Coffee 9", "9"));
                    items.add(new Item("Coffee 10", "10"));
                } else {
                    items.add(new Item("Milk 1", "1"));
                    items.add(new Item("Milk 2", "2"));
                    items.add(new Item("Milk 3", "3"));
                    items.add(new Item("Milk 4", "4"));
                    items.add(new Item("Milk 5", "5"));
                    items.add(new Item("Milk 6", "6"));
                    items.add(new Item("Milk 7", "7"));
                    items.add(new Item("Milk 8", "8"));
                    items.add(new Item("Milk 9", "9"));
                    items.add(new Item("Milk 10", "10"));
                }

                final ItemAdapter mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(items);

                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
                paint.setColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.md_grey_500, null));
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{25.0f, 25.0f}, 0));
                mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(getActivity()).showLastDivider().paint(paint).build()); //.marginResId(R.dimen.leftmargin, R.dimen.rightmargin)

                collection.addView(rootView);


                return rootView;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view)    {
                collection.removeView((View) view);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 2;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view == object;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                //CustomPagerEnum customPagerEnum = CustomPagerEnum.values()[position];
                return position == 0 ? "Coffee" : "Milk";
            }

        }
    }
```

**It's Done.**

[image]

Comment: it will lose the scroll state from previous page because you are just recreating the adapter and rebinding to tablayout every time a user swipe left/right. not only it's dirty and expensive, it cause flickering while the page is relayouting. I'm actually looking for a solution which you transfer the `fling` event/calculation to the active page of the viewpager.